# Passing text between activities with an Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm having some difficulty getting the intent's extras to be passed between activities. I'm a beginner at android and even this small thing is really bothering me.

I'm trying to pass the information entered into the EditText in MyActivity.java to the TextView in DisplayMessageActivity.java when I press a button.

Here's the MyActivity.java code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "myfirstapp.example.com.myapplication.MESSAGE";

public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent message_send = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText edit_message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = edit_message.getText().toString();
    message_send.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    MyActivity.this.startActivity(message_send);
}
```

And here's the code for DisplayMessageActivity.java:

```
 public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

@Overide
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent message_send = getIntent();
    String message = message_send.getStringExtra(MyActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
}
```

If anyone could tell me what is happening, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for an explanation of how it works, or is it not working as expected?

Answer (score 2):

`DisplayMessageActivity` is creating a new `TextView` and setting the passed-in message, but the new `TextView` is not displayed anywhere.

most likely, instead of creating a new `TextView`, you'll want to `setContentView` first, and then call `findViewById` to locate your `TextView`.

the string passing code is all correct.

```
@Overide
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
    Intent message_send = getIntent();
    String message = message_send.getStringExtra(MyActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);
}
```

Comment: please remember to upvote/accept if this resolves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In `dispalyActivity`  you can  use this code

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtra();
String message = b.getString("message name");
```

instead of

```
Intent message_send = getIntent(); 
String message = message_send.getStringExtra(MyActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
```